# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input - not able to find syntax error if it is

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm getting error for code mentioned below. Most of the answers there suggest that there is some syntax error for this kind of error but I'm not able to find it yet. Can anybody help.

> Error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>      at JSON.parse ()
>      at Object.error ((index):20)
>      at i (df983.js:2)
>      at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (df983.js:2)
>      at y (df983.js:2)
>      at XMLHttpRequest.c (df983.js:2)

```js
jQuery("#registersend").click(function() {
  var $ = jQuery;
  var regdata = $(".registerdata");
  var ok = true;
  regdata.removeClass("error2");

  for (var i = 0; i < regdata.length; i++) {
    if ($(regdata[i]).val() == "") {
      $(regdata[i]).addClass("error2");
      ok = false;
    }
  }

  if (ok) {
    var form2 = $('<form ><input type="hidden" id="firstname2" name="firstname"><input type="hidden" id="lastname2" name="lastname"><input type="hidden" id="login2" name="login"><input id="registerandlogin2" name="submit" type="submit" value="registerandlogin" > </form>');
    form2.children("#firstname2").val($("#registername").val());
    form2.children("#lastname2").val(" ");
    form2.children("#login2").val($("#registerlogin").val());
    form2.appendTo('body');

    var firstname = $("#firstname2").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname2").val();
    var login = $("#login2").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.getdrip.com/forms/37709616/submissions',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        login: login
      },
      success: function(data) {
        form2.submit();
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      }
    });

    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="https://app.bouncezap.com/my/register.php"><input type="hidden" id="firstname" name="firstname"><input type="hidden" id="lastname" name="lastname"><input type="hidden" id="login" name="login"><input type="hidden" id="password" name="password"><input type="hidden" id="password2" name="password2"><input id="registerandlogin" name="submit" type="submit" value="registerandlogin" ></form>');
    form.children("#firstname").val($("#registername").val());
    form.children("#lastname").val(" ");
    form.children("#login").val($("#registerlogin").val());
    form.children("#password").val($("#registerpassword").val());
    form.children("#password2").val($("#registerpassword").val());
    form.appendTo('body');
    form.children("#registerandlogin").click();
  }
})
```

Comment: That error means there's an issue with the response from the server, not your code - although it is *very* odd that you're creating a `form` element from a HTML string and then reading the values from it...?

Comment: You should post the response body, which I assume is a server error, and not JSON. Hence the SyntaxError.